# Strcpy() function parameters

Tags: c, strcpy

I am using the function `strcpy()` a lot for an assignment. Looking at the function prototype for `strcpy()`:

```
char *strcpy(char *dest, const char *src)
```

It can be seen that `strcpy()` takes in two pointers.

However, I have seen in a lot of examples online as well as in my own code that a string can be copied in the following manner and it will work:

```
char array[30];
strcpy(array, "mystring");
printf("%s\n", array);
```

My question is, why does `strcpy()` work if the second parameter that you're passing is a string? Wouldn't the second parameter need be a pointer to a string? E.g. wouldn't you have to do the following:

```
const char *str = "mystring";
char array[30];
strcpy(array, str);
printf("%s\n", array);
```

I'm confused about why you can directly pass a string as the second parameter to `strcpy()` and not a pointer to the string. Any insights would be really appreciated.

Comment: A string in C reduces to a pointer to the first element/character in this case.

Comment: C does not have a string type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the special relationship between arrays and pointers in C.

Formally, a string in C is an array of `char`.  But pointers in C can *very* easily be used to access arrays, such that 'pointer to `char`' is often as useful a type for manipulating strings as 'array of `char`' is.  Furthermore, any time you use an array (including a string constant) in an expression where its value is needed, what you get (automatically) is a pointer to the array's first element.

That is, if you say

```
char array[10];
char *p = array;
```

it is precisely as if you had said

```
char *p = &array[0];
```

And since a string constant (formally, a *string literal*) is an array of `char`, if you say

```
p = "mystring";
```

or

```
strcpy(array, "mystring");
```

it is exactly as if you had said

```
p = &"mystring"[0];
```

or

```
strcpy(array, &"mystring"[0]);
```

So you don't need to add your own `&` in these cases, and if you do, it's not quite right, because what you end up with is 'pointer to array' rather than 'pointer to `char`' which is what you want.

The syntax `&"mystring"[0]` is very strange, and no one would ever use it, and it probably makes this explanation pretty confusing.  Let's do it a slightly different way.  If you say

```
char mystring[] = "mystring";
p = mystring;
```

or

```
strcpy(array, mystring);
```

it is exactly as if you had said

```
p = &mystring[0];
```

or

```
strcpy(array, &mystring[0]);
```

When you call `strcpy(array, &mystring[0])` you are passing a `char *` to `strcpy`, as required.  If you were to call

```
strcpy(array, &mystring);   /* WRONG */
```

you would be passing a 'pointer to array of `char`' (or `char *[]`) instead, which would be wrong.  (It might even end up seeming to work, which might confuse you into thinking it was proper, but it's not.)

Answer (score 3):

Because in C the type of a string literal is `char[]` : http://c0x.coding-guidelines.com/6.4.5.html

> [...For character string literals, the array elements have type char...]

Comment: Wouldn't you have to assign the string literal to a variable prior to using it in strcpy (e.g. char *x = "string")? Or is it just fine to pass the string directly, since it'll be reduced to a pointer?

Comment: @ceno980 It doesn't matter when the array decays to a pointer.

Comment: @ceno980 If a literal already has a machting type as you need, copying to a variable doesn't gain anything.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm confused about why you can directly pass a string as the second parameter to strcpy() and not a pointer to the string. Any insights would be really appreciated.

You do have to pass a pointer to a c-string for both arguments, or at least something that can *decay* to such a pointer. The type char array `char[]` (which is the type of string literals) can do that.

Remember though that a c-string is not a type. It is a continuous sequence of bytes terminated by the first `\0`.

Here is an enlightening example:

```
char c[30] = "Hello\0 \0World!\n";
printf("%s%s%s\n", &c[0],&c[6],&c[8] );
```

The char array `c` has size 30. It contains three c-strings: "Hello", " ", and "World!\n". Their lengths are 5, 1, and 7 and the amount of space they occupy in the array is 6, 2, and 8 respectively.